# Create a webpack build to an angular-cli application

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Here where I work, we have the challenge to create a platform using the micro frontends concept, and we decide to give a shot to the Single-SPA framework.

But the setup that I founded, it's necessary the micro app to be an UMD or AMD module, and I try a few times, to create a npm script to build an existing angular-cli project to webpack, but it's was'nt posible.

My question is, there is any way to create a webpack build in existing angular-cli generated project?

Thanks!

Comment: Angular 5 and below, have concept of ng eject, which will allow to customize webpack config. From Angular 6, they have disabled the webpack customization. So it's not possible in latest angular framework using Angular CLI. You can use Webpack with Angular Framework without CLI https://blog.angularindepth.com/upgrading-a-project-without-cli-to-angular-6-b07b105adc02

Comment: But in angular 6 they have a concept of builders, and with this builders I can create a custom one generating an UMD or AMD bundle right?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Angular 5 and if the other comment does not help, you might want to go through:
https://v5.angular.io/guide/webpack

Hope it helps!